# Extra characters in end of string when using MQC MQMessage WriteString in C# CharacterSet 819 Encoding 273

Tags: c#-4.0, character-encoding, ibm-mq

I have a huge problem. Most of the time when I send a message to my customers message queue server there appears some "invisible" characters at the end of the message. The characters are only visible in my cutomers log, not in for example Notepad++. The last word in the message string is an email address, can it be the @ who causes the trouble? I've got the message "Wrong email address" back from the MQ server. In the customers log the email address looks like this "fname.ename@address.se;XINT;" and other times like this "fname.ename@address.se;[[;" Here is my C# code:

```
var message = "some text   some text   some other text   fname.ename@address.se    ";
var corr = new byte[24];
for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++)
{
    corr[i] = byte.Parse("20", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
}

var mess = new MQMessage
{
    ReplyToQueueName = queueRead,
    CorrelationId = corr,
    UserId = userId,
    ApplicationIdData = userPwd,
    CharacterSet = 819,
    Encoding = 273,
    Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING
};
mess.WriteString(message);

var pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions(); 

queue.Put(mess, pmo);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved! The specification I've got from the customer was incomplete. The length of last field in the message should be multiplicated with 7 which I didn't knew. But now I know!